# Order by on Two Datetime Fields .If one field is Null How to avoid Sybase from populating it with default datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, sybase, sap-ase

I am using a Select Query to insert data  into a Temp Table .In the Select Query I am doing  order by on two columns something like this

```
insert into #temp 

Select accnt_no,acct_name, start_date,end_date From table 

Order by start_date DESC,end_date DESC
Select * from #temp
```

Here when there is an entry present in start_date field and an Null entry in the end_date field .During the order by operation Sybase is filling it with an Default date ( jan 1 1900 ) . I dont want that to happen .If the end_date field is Null . The data should be written just as Null .Any suggestion on how to keep it as Null even while fetching the data from the table .

Comment: Are you sure this is really caused by the "order by operation"?

Comment: yes @shawnt00 . since sybase needs something to do an order by it populates the null values with default date (1900-01-01)

Comment: Where did you get that idea? Nulls are generally sorted separately and can come first or last depending on the platform and other settings available. See Oracle for example. It doesn' need to "populate" them.

Comment: 7 Test  Sep 25 2014 12:00AM  JAN 1 1900 12:00:00 AM .
This is the Sample output i grt from QUery . For this Field end_date--> JAN 1 1900 12:00:00 AM  ,I have not given Any manula entry .sybase itself created this output when doing an Order by

Comment: If you do the same thing only without ordering by the end_date, does it still fill in the value?

Comment: Sorry,My bad i understood Wrongly . Even though when i didnt do an order by based on end_date DESC it is loading with Default values

Comment: You should probably update your question.  People don't want to read all the comments to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Run this query or just supply us with the #temp table create script: select name, cdefault from tempdb..syscolumns c where c.id = object_id('tempdb..#temp')

Comment: /*This should give us any defaults on the table:*/ select c.name, object_name(cdefault), text from tempdb..syscolumns c, tempdb..syscomments cm where c.id = object_id('tempdb..#temp') and cm.id = c.cdefault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1/1/1900 usually comes from trying to cast an empty string into a datetime.

Is your 'date' source column an actual datetime datatype or a string-ish varchar or char?

Comment: I only get to (have to) dabble in Sybase as a longtime SQL Server developer and I forgot about that case. You probably nailed it.

Comment: MS SQL server has the same behavior as Sybase in this regard.

Comment: I thought about testing it on Sql Server before writing that. It might still around precisely because of the Sybase heritage but then I don't if that explains why '' casts to zero. I guess I find it easy to forget some of these behaviors since it's usually so bad to rely on them although I did recently use `cast(2015 as datetime)' to default to the first day of the year.

Comment: I found that ,it was actually an datetime field and i ran an convert function on  that particular field while whetching the data . It was creating all this Fuss . Have removed that and solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the table definition requires that end_date not be null, and has default values inserted automatically to prevent them.  Are you sure there are even nulls when you do a straight select on the table without the confusion of ordering and inserting?

Answer (score 0):

I created a temp table with a nullable datetime column that has a default value.

Defaults are not there to handle nulls per se, they are there to handle missing values on inserts that were not supplied. If I run an insert without a column list (just as you have done) the default value does not apply and a null is still inserted.

I suggest adding the column list to your insert statement. This might prevent the problem (or expose a different problem in having them in the wrong order.)

```
insert into #temp (accnt_no, accnt_name, start_date, end_date)
select accnt_no,acct_name, start_date,end_date from ...
```

Here's a query that should help you find the actual defaults on any of the columns if you don't have access to the create script:

```
select c.name, object_name(cdefault), text
from tempdb..syscolumns c, tempdb..syscomments cm
where c.id = object_id('tempdb..#temp') and cm.id = c.cdefault
```